# ios-trash-outline does not appear

Tags: ionic-framework

I try to use the specific icon without success. When I try to use the standard trash icon then it appears. It seems that its size automatically becomes 0x0. I tried to increase the size and change colors but without success.
This is my code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label (click)="doSomething()">something</ion-label>
  <ion-icon item-end name="trash-outline" ios="ios-trash-outline" md="md-trash-outline" class="trash_icon" (click)="delete()"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```